# How can I find orphaned entries between related tables in a database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two mySQL tables, representing documents that were published in particular journals:

```
Documents: 

ID Title                          Journal
1  Monty: A New Study             6
2  New Discoveries about Python   17
3  An Unpublished Document        NULL 

Journals: 

ID Title 
6  Journal of Foo
10 Orphans Weekly 
17 Journal of Bar
99 Journal of Orphans
```

Here, the document "Monty: A New Study" was published in Journal of Foo, and "New Discoveries about Python" was published in the illustrious journal called Journal of Bar.

The problem is, for whatever reason there are journal titles that don't have associated documents, namely #10 and #99. I want to delete all the entries of journals that don't have associated documents. I want to do something like:

```
delete from Journals where id is not one of (select journal from documents where journal is not null)
```

But I'm new to mySQL and got stuck on this.

Comment: Use InnoDB and create foreign key constraints with cascading deletes and updates.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM `Journals` AS j WHERE j.ID NOT EXISTS(SELECT Journal FROM `Documents`);
```

or...

```
DELETE FROM `Journals` AS j WHERE j.ID NOT IN (SELECT Journal FROM `Documents`);
```

Comment: Getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS J WHERE J.ID NOT IN (SELECT journal FROM `documents`)' at line 1"

Comment: Please post the full query you are trying. Also, make sure everything matches your table/column names. Also... those are backticks and not apostrophes around "Journals".

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as follows;

```
delete from Journals where id not in (SELECT Journal from Documents)
```

Comment: and you can see the records to be deleted as follows;

`select * from Journals where id is not in (SELECT Journal from Documents)`

Comment: I'm getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'in (SELECT Journal from Documents) LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1"